# Using the Network Link Conditioner on iOS devices

Tags: ios

How can I simulate various network conditions directly on my iOS device? I know this is possible on a Mac thanks to the [Network Link Conditioner](http://mattgemmell.com/2011/07/25/network-link-conditioner-in-lion/). Is there something similar on iOS devices?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes, with iOS 6, it is now possible to use the Network Link Conditioner directly on your iOS device, if your device is set to be enabled for development.

Simply go to `Settings > Developer > Network Link Conditioner` to enable it.

If you don't see `Settings > Developer`, to enable it:

1. Connect your iPhone to your Mac.
2. `Xcode > Organizer`
3. Select your iPhone.
4. Click Use for Development.

I've noticed that sometimes the Developer menu item disappears. It reappears again when installing an app using Xcode.

Comment: It's unfortunate that the Apple Reachability project doesn't take note of these simulated connection profiles.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try with Reachability. So switching between (preset profiles) 3G and Wifi will not cause Reachability to notify that the network medium has changed?

Comment: Worse than that, Reachability ignores these developer network profiles. I've filed a bug with Apple about this.

Comment: I have iOS 6.0.1 (10A523). I don't see Settings > Developer. How do I get it?

Comment: Nevermind. I found it and updated the answer to include instructions to enable it.

Comment: I don't have an iPhone handy right now, can I get the Network Link Conditioner within the iOS simulator? In the iOS simulator, I see Settings > Developer But can't find the Network Link Conditioner there after. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MoizTankiwala there is a way on Mac OS to turn on the Network Link Conditioner, but it won't be specifically for the simulator.

Comment: Yup, if you want it on the simulator, then you get it for your Mac.
http://nshipster.com/network-link-conditioner/

Answer (score 6):

Might also mention that the `developer` option doesn't show up in `settings` sometimes until you tether the device and launch Xcode.

Close Settings>tether device>launch Xcode> Open Settings

Answer (score 3):

So strange thing happened for me and hopefully it'll save someone the hassle.
I had my phone set to developer mode as I've used to build multiple apps previously.
For some reason, searching "Network Link Conditioner" in Settings doesn't bring up anything. Searching "Developer" brings up the Apple Developer app (if you have it installed) that shows info about WWDC videos, news etc. about Apple development.
For a little while I thought my phone wasn't in developer mode but scrolling thru Settings to see the other "Developer" option for actual developer settings of the device, its still there.

Answer (score 2):

As an update for iOS8, and for people confused about the next step, if you have already gotten to the step in which you deploy to your device, all you need to do is go to on the device > Settings > Developer > Network Link Conditioner.