# Disabling network on iPad during UIAutomation Testing

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, ios-simulator, ui-automation

Is there a way to disable and then enable the network on simulator for UIAutomation. I working on an application which has to display a notification bar on the app when network is disabled and I wish to test it out using UIAutomation.

Please suggest.

Comment: +1 for good question - curious for any answer to come...

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a full answer for you, but I do have some references that might help.

One of Apple's developer tools on OS X is the Network Link Conditioner, which can be used to simulate various network conditions.  These include "drop all packets" (although I suspect this may not be what you mean by "network disabled").

[This post](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/01/30/network-link-conditioner.html) explains the tool quite well.  Note though that it is now an optional download (details [here](http://juehualu.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/network-link-conditioner-ios.html)).

The same feature (with the same name) is built in to iOS (min iOS 6 apparently, on the device only, not the simulator).  It can be set up by going to `Settings > Developer > Network Link Conditioner` - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528986/using-the-network-link-conditioner-on-ios-devices).

I don't know if it is possible to enable / disable these via UIAutomation, sorry.

Comment: I tried to search for doing this but no as far as I find this is not possible.