# Not seeing developer menu under settings on iOS device

Tags: ios, xcode

Following the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12528987/62) to show the `Settings > Developer` menu on iOS, I don't see the "Use for Development" setting on Xcode 8.2.1 and an iOS 10.2.1 device. I believe I have previously selected "Use for Development" with this device (which may be why I don't see that button anymore) but I don't see the Developer menu under the iOS Settings app. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you able to connect and see your iPhone under Xcode?

Comment: Yes. I see the device in the devices list.

Comment: Stay connected and go to Settings. Search for **Status** in the search bar. Do you see anything in the search result list ?

Comment: Weird, that worked! Now I see the developer menu. Thanks. Maybe write that as an answer not a comment?

Comment: Great!! Enjoy..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`Just so everyone knows a workaround for this.`**

**Steps:**

- Connect your iPhone and make sure you can see your iPhone in the Xcode.
- Stay connected, and go to iOS Settings.
- Search for **Status** in the search bar at the top.
- Look for the **Developer-> Network Link Conditioner** in search
  result list.
- It takes you to **Developer Settings**. Now you always see
  **Developer** option in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

In my iPhone I saw the developer menu only when I switch the language to English.

`Settings -> General -> Language & Region -> iPhone Language`